# Can OpenLayers layers in QGIS have transparency?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I often would like to set the basemap back by lowering the transparency. I would love to have this option in QGIS for OpenLayers layers, such as the stamen layers, google, etc.

Is this possible?

I don't see the ability in the layer properties or within the raster transparency plugin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no transparency for OpenLayers layers. My usual work-around is to put a layer with a big white transparent polygon on top.

Background map layer transparancy can be changed if you use the QuickMapServices plugin instead:

[image]

Comment: Other chance is to save the screen as georeferenced image, and add that to canvas instead of the plugin layer.

Answer (score 4):

You can in fact change the transparency or opacity of openlayer rasters, by amending the openlayer plugin html file.

For instruction of how to edit the html file, please see this link:
http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2012-February/015648.html

Answer (score 0):

Like Andre Joost notes, you can also "save as image" the area of interest and afterwords upload the saved raster file on your qgis project and so on edit the transparency.